# How can I get the original line number and symbol from a sourcemap

Tags: javascript, minify, bundling-and-minification, source-maps

I'm logging javascript errors from my site, but the files are minimized so I don't get meaningful line numbers. I do have source maps, however.

Is there a service, script, npm module, or anything that can help me "translate" the line numbers from the minified versions into something useful?

Comment: Do you have a test/integration environment with non-minified JS that you can reproduce those errors in?

Comment: Of course I do, but a basic part of error logging is reading stacktraces...do you not agree?

Comment: I'm just wondering if what you need is required for production, given the 'answer' is just beautified JS.

Comment: I have a system in production, and a stacktrace from a bug on production. Obviously I need to be able to reproduce it. I'm asking how I can effectively read my stacktrace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the answer using this npm module:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/source-map

**Edit Feb 1st, 2015**

Found the following project which handles this: https://github.com/epeli/source-map-peek

Comment: Thanks for doing this research.  It helps.  Better, but I really want to be able to log source locations at the client, when the client gets an error.  The WebPack/Babel config module.exports.devtool has a value 'nosources-source-map' designed for production; it provides file-name and line-number detail, without giving away the source code.  In the debugger, it works fine.  But my clients are not in the debugger.  On error, my code pops a window, asking user to copy and paste into an email.  That stack-trace is my lifeline.  I need filename and line number there.  But string is just min info.